# Loading a JSON file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm having some issues with JSON and javascript. What I want to do is to have a JSON file which contains some information about an object that I will want to render using Three.js. For example my JSON file would have the width height and depth values of a cube I want to make, and I want to be able to pull these out of the JSON file and use them as parameters for my cube geometry. Currently I have the JSON information saved as a string to a variable like this:

```
var text = '{"floorx":"11","floorz":"4","cabinets":[{"cabx":"1", "cabz":"2","width":"90", "depth":"130", "height":"200", "orientation":"N"}, {"cabx":"2.2", "cabz":"2","width":"90", "depth":"130", "height":"200", "orientation":"N"}, {"cabx":"5", "cabz":"2","width":"90", "depth":"130", "height":"200", "orientation":"N"}]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(text);
var floor1 = floor(obj.floorx,obj.floorz);
scene.add(floor1);
```

Which is working exactly how I want it to. What I'm having bother with now is extracting the JSON code saved to var text and putting it into it's own JSON file and reading this in. I have tried AJAX but I'm not even sure if thats what I want. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: if you have that literal `{"floorx"...}` text in a file, then all you'd need is a jquery call: `$.getJSON('/path/to/file.json', function(data) { var obj = data });`

Comment: If you try to access the local file system with JavaScript - you can't (JavaScript sandbox security). You need a web server to send you the files. If you have a web server, Ajax is the right approach.

Comment: " I have tried AJAX but I'm not even sure if thats what I want" — It is what you want. You need to show us your failed attempts before we can tell you why it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in two ways. One is indeed by making an AJAX request. Really simple if you are using e.g. jQuery or AngularJS (but there are many many other frameworks that make this really easy). Note that if you do it like this, you need to manually parse the input by using e.g. JSON.parse. In order to have this pass, you should remove the var definition that is in front of your JSON expression and assign the output of JSON.parse to a variable.

If you don't want to use an AJAX request, you could also just include your JSON code as a regular Javascript file. So, put this in a separate file, /some_file.js:

```
var text = '{"floorx":"11","floorz":"4","cabinets":[{"cabx":"1", "cabz":"2","width":"90", "depth":"130", "height":"200", "orientation":"N"}, {"cabx":"2.2", "cabz":"2","width":"90", "depth":"130", "height":"200", "orientation":"N"}, {"cabx":"5", "cabz":"2","width":"90", "depth":"130", "height":"200", "orientation":"N"}]}';
```

And then include it in your HTML with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/some_file.js">
```

Basically, both of these methods operate in the same way, since in both cases your browser will issue an extra request to load the extra file, but the latter is probably somewhat easier.

Comment: Thank you, I get it sorted with JQuery :)